# Azure App Service - GitHub Action - WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE Not Running

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I am using the following GH Action to Build/Publish my .NET API.

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327652/error-with-github-action-deploy-to-azure-web-app
name: API-zip

on: 
  push:
    # only trigger on branches, not on tags
    branches: '**'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.0.x
        dotnet-quality: 'preview'

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish 'App.Api\App.Api.csproj' -r linux-x64 -f net8.0 -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/app --self-contained --nologo

    - name: Upload Build Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: app-${{ github.run_number }}
        path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/app

  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    
    steps:
    - name: Downlod Artifacts 
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3

    - name: List Files
      run: ls -R

    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.52.0
        inlineScript: |
          az login --service-principal \
          -u ** \
          -p ** \
          -t **

    - name: Deploy to Azure
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.52.0
        inlineScript: |
          zip -r app-${{ github.run_number }}.zip .
          ls -R
          az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group App --name App-zip --src app-${{ github.run_number }}.zip
```

It successfully completes and publishes a ZIP file to my Linux App Service.

[image]

However, when I attempt to view the App, it's still showing me the `wwwroot` default HTML page. I do have `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1` in my App Settings. I noticed when trouble shooting I extracted the ZIP file locally that it's not zipping the raw files, but putting them in a folder first (see image)

[image]

Is this part of the problem? I tried just zipping the files themselves and re-uploading manually (to eliminate the parent folder) but it still didn't pickup the App.

What is wrong here?

Comment: `that it's not zipping the raw files, but putting them in a folder first` ..AFAIK,that is the default behavior of the zipped folder from the deployed app.

Comment: Could you please share your GitHub repo if possible..so that I can deploy the same app and check.

Comment: In azure app service => Configuration section  => general settings => Startup command,add `dotnet yourappname.dll` and check once.

Comment: how do i get the raw files into the Zip as opposed to a folder first? is there documentation that talks about the startup command? i wouldn't think i have to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using this updated GH Action:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327652/error-with-github-action-deploy-to-azure-web-app
name: api

on: [workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.0.x
        dotnet-quality: 'preview'

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish 'app\app.csproj' -r linux-x64 -f net8.0 -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/app --self-contained --nologo

    - name: Upload Build Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: app-${{ github.run_number }}
        path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/app
        retention-days: 1

  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    
    steps:
    - name: Downlod Artifacts 
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3

    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.52.0
        inlineScript: |
          az login --service-principal \
          -u z \
          -p y \
          -t x

    - name: Deploy to Azure
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.52.0
        inlineScript: |
          zip -r -j app-${{ github.run_number }}.zip ./app-${{ github.run_number }}
          ls -a
          az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group app --name app --src app-${{ github.run_number }}.zip --timeout 360
```

Answer (score 0):

As .net 8.0 is still in Preview not all the Features are available for Deploying your Asp.net core API. Thus while deploying the Asp.net core API or any API in Azure Web app its necessary to use Deployment mode as self contained while deploying your Web API to Web app like below:-

**Reference -** [SO Thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77123530/azure-app-service-hosted-on-net-8-preview-linux-does-not-start-up-apparently-a/77131914#) **By Pravallika and comment by YMC**

I created one Asp.net core 8.0 Web API and while deployment selected Self contained as Deployment Type like below:-

[image]

And After clicking on Publish the Web API was deployed successfully like below:-

[image]

I have also connected one APIM instance for managing the API while deployment like below, you can skip this step:-

[image]

**UPDATED Solution:-**

By default [**`az webapp deployment source config-zip`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deployment-source-config-zip%28%29) **does not contain a parameter to add --self-contained as Deployment mode**, **Thus you need to add your `--self-contained` zip artifact in your az webapp deployment command in your github workflow like below:-**

**My updated github workflow steps with the cli zip method:-**

- Make sure the artifact path you are using is correct, Cross-check it in your Download Artifact step in the deploy stage.
- My downloaded artifact path where I added .zip suffix :-
  **`/home/runner/work/WebApplication16/WebApplication16.zip`**

Also, I have added the Azure CLI service principal credentials as a github secret, Refer below:-

Created service principal with contributor role at subscription level and added the output as a github secret:-

```bash
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "sp-name" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/xxxxxxxsub-id --sdk-auth
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Copied this output in the secrets:-**

[image]

**My github action workflow script with zip command:-**

```yaml
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327652/error-with-github-action-deploy-to-azure-web-app
name: API-zip

on: 
  push:
    # only trigger on branches, not on tags
    branches: '**'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.0.x
        dotnet-quality: 'preview'
        
    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release 

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r linux-x64 -o ${{ github.workspace }}/.net-app
        # Adjust the runtime identifier (-r) to match your target platform.

    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/.net-app

  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
          name: .net-app

    - name: Configure Azure credentials
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: Deploy to Azure
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.52.0
        inlineScript: |
          zip -r /home/runner/work/WebApplication16/WebApplication16.zip .
          ls -R
          az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group valleyrg54 --name siliconwebapp098 --src /home/runner/work/WebApplication16/WebApplication16.zip
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**API got deployed in Azure web app and is running successfully with /WeatherForecast:-**

https://.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast

[image]

***An alternative method is to use azure/webapps-deploy@v2 task like below:-***

***My github action workflow:-***

I have created a default workflow by connecting my github repository with the Azure Web app via Deployment Center **and then edited the workflow code** like below:-

[image]

**My [**repository**](https://github.com/sid24desai/WebApplication16) with .net 8.0 core API:-**

[image]

**Edited the workflow file  with `--self-contained and -r linux-x64`  flag like below:-**

**Workflow code:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy ASP.NET Core app to Azure Web App - valleywebapp21

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r linux-x64 -o ${{ github.workspace }}/.net-app
        # Adjust the runtime identifier (-r) to match your target platform.

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/.net-app

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'valleywebapp21'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_3AFD052BFF7A47D398D058E0DB22F706 }}
          package: /home/runner/work/WebApplication16/WebApplication16
```

***Cross check where your artifacts are downloaded in your build job in deploy stage and add that path in the package at Deploy to Azure Web App step as my script above:-***

[image]

**Web API deployed successfully:-**

[image]

***I am able to access WeatherForecast API like below after deployment:-***

[image]

Comment: thanks for the details - but if you review my original answer i'm already passing the self-contained flag. my issue isn't deploying the web app to the Azure wwwroot folder, it's the zip package deployment that isn't work.

Comment: @aherrick  I have updated my answer. Kindly check the UPDATED Solution:- section where I have used az webapp deployment source config-zip method in my workflow, Try my method and my workflow.

Comment: I have used - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r linux-x64 -o ${{ github.workspace }}/.net-app downloaded the artifact, And used your cli step to zip the artifact and deploy it via cli -         inlineScript: |
          zip -r /home/runner/work/WebApplication16/WebApplication16.zip .
          ls -R
          az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group valleyrg54 --name siliconwebapp098 --src /home/runner/work/WebApplication16/WebApplication16.zip

Comment: @aherrick Was my UPDATED Solution helpful?

Comment: it was but it wasn't the correct answer. appreciate your support