# Getting 404 when trying to call Azure Web App url using Service hooks in Azure devops

Tags: azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-404, azure-service-hooks

Created a new web app using [git repo](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions.git) code, however when I try to call web app url using service hook in ADO, getting 404 error.

What web app url should I use [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions/blob/master/media/web-hooks-2.png)?

Currently am using default domain url which can be found on overview page of web app along with 'api/receiver/webhook/workitem/update' as mentioned in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops#automate-state-transitions-of-parent-work) Automate State Transitions [Github project](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions) is no longer supported in the Azure Boards and the same repository is now Archived by the author.

> [image]

***I deployed the same web app from the Github project and tried adding it to the Webhook and received the same error, Refer below:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

As a workaround you can  Deploy an **`Asp.net core API`** in your Azure Web app or integrate any  third party API with your current web app, Refer my [SO thread answer for deploying the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151698/azure-app-service-github-action-website-run-from-package-not-running/77178447#77178447) and then use it in your PostURL like below:-

I am using a sample - [reqres.in/api/users](https://reqres.in/api/users) API

[image]

[image]

If you want to link your build and release of your Azure Web app to your Work Items Link your Deployment to the work item for the Deployment tracking. Refer [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/configure-pipelines-work-tracking?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#classic-report-boards).

[image]

If you want to send a Post HTTP request after the Work Item is updated you can make use of Azure Logic Apps as an alternative and utilize HTTP Request and Work Item connectors, Refer below:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Siddhesh but my actual requirement was to update the PBI state automatically when my task state gets change in azure board due to which I was using that repo. Would you be able to help there?

Comment: Then directly linking the deployments to Work Items will do the needful, The deployments will be tracked in the workitems once you add it to your build or release pipelines. You can add that work item in your Power BI like here-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-dataset?view=azure-devops#data-relationships