# dotnetcore web api hosted on azure app service is not working until I set virtual path to the sub directories

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, publish, azure-cli

I hosted a dotnet core web API, into Azure app service manually using Azure CLI. I used the CI-generated package for Zip deployment. The package structure looks like
[image: CI package folder structure]
.xml and .nuspec are generated by CI in the process of generating my app build artifacts. Which holds metadata about the package generated by CI.
I used this information and published it to my app service as it is using Azure CLI zip deployment.
My application was built on .netcore2.1
But my project-related stuff resides under x64 > Release > netcoreapp2.1 > win7-x64
win7-x64 folder contains a folder ex: "xyz" which holds all the information (.exe, *.dll, *.json, *.config, etc) about the project.

I used this information to publish to the app service. After publishing the folder structure on the app service under wwwroot looks same as the the package given by CI. Looks like this on the KUDU UI
[image: Folder stucture under wwwroot]

When I started browsing the hosted app, it gave 500 errors.
[image: 500 error]

After some research on setting a virtual path on the app service, I configured a virtual path under the configuration > path mapping section of the app service, which maps the folder path to actual project files where it was residing.
[image: setting virtual path]
It is configured to x64 > Release > netcoreapp2.1 > win7-x64 > xyz folder for the virtual path. Then my application started working perfectly.

I don't want my application to be hosted as a virtual application under site\wwwroot of Azure app service. I want to run my app under the root folder not as a virtual or sub-application. the package generated by CI has only one application-related stuff. At the same time, I don't want to alter the way that my package got generated by CI (folder structure by CI). How to make my application run under the root folder?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying the .NET Core API build folder with **`Azure CLI`** **`Zip command`** and it was successful, Refer below:-

My **`Build folder`** contains the below files:-

[image]

My **CLI command** to deploy the Web API:-

```bash
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group siliconrg65 --name siliconwebapp097 --src "C:\Users\v-sidesai\source\repos\WebApplication48\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish.zip"
```

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

My **`wwwroot`**:-

[image]

In order to perform CI/CD pipeline with build and deploy with zip command, Refer my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151698/azure-app-service-github-action-website-run-from-package-not-running/77178447#).